# How do I create a variable in go only if a condition is true?

Tags: variables, go

If I create a variable inside an if block, I can't use it later on. If I create a variable before the if block and the if block evaluates to false, I get a "variable created and not used" error.

I'm certain that this is by design and I'm trying to do something I shouldn't, but the logic behind what I'm trying to do makes sense to me. If there is page info in the url, I want to use it in a sql statement later on, but if there isn't page info in the url, then I don't need those variables.

http://pastebin.com/QqwpdM1d

Edit: here's the code:

```
var pageID string
var offset int
if len(r.URL.Path) > len("/page/") {
    pageID := r.URL.Path[len("/page/"):]
    offset, err := strconv.Atoi(pageID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
conn := "..."
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conn)
defer db.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var rows *sql.Rows
if offset != 0 {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare a variable before an `if` statement and you use it inside the `if` block, it doesn't matter what the condition evaluates to, it is not a compile time error.

The error in you case is that you don't use the declared variable inside the `if` block. Your code:

```
var pageID string
var offset int
if len(r.URL.Path) > len("/page/") {
    pageID := r.URL.Path[len("/page/"):]
    offset, err := strconv.Atoi(pageID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Inside the `if` you are not assigning to the previously declared `pageID`, but you are using [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) `:=` which creates a new variable, shadowing the one created in the outer block, and it is in effect only at the end of the `if` block (its scope ends at the end of the innermost containing block).

Solution is (what you most likely wanted to) simply use assignment `=` (which assigns value to the existing variable):

```
    pageID = r.URL.Path[len("/page/"):]
```

---

To make it understand, see this example:

```
i := 1
fmt.Println("Outer:", i)
{
    i := 2 // Short var decl: creates a new i, shadowing the outer
    fmt.Println("Inner:", i)
}
fmt.Println("Outer again:", i)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/u1CUUWA3DJ)):

```
Outer: 1
Inner: 2
Outer again: 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I definitely didn't mean to re-initialize pageID. What about offset, err :=... since err is a new variable? Will go assume that I'm only initializing err since offset already exists and I need the value later on?

Comment: @sup3rs3nior It will create 2 new variables, because `offset` was declared in the containing block. But read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), because using short variable declaration where 1 variable is new and 1 variable already exists which it was declared in the _same_ block, that is a _redeclaration_ which will only assign a new value to the existing one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should or shouldn't use the short variable declaration. If I use it, I get variable initialized and not used, if I don't, I get undefined. http://play.golang.org/p/WsQ1m_4ReK

Comment: @sup3rs3nior Since you want the value to be visible after the block, you can't / musn't use short variable declaration. So you have to use assignment `=`. But assignment requires all variable to be declared prior. So before calling `loader()`, declare the `err` variable, e.g. `var err string`. See working example: http://play.golang.org/p/F9IZQW-7qH

Comment: I'm a little worried that the first time I've ever seen an err initialized before getting a value is in my code. Do you think that's an indicator that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @sup3rs3nior Not particularly in the last example you showed here. When this is the exact situation (you assign in a block after which you need the value) it is common that a variable needs to be declared first before calling a function having multi-return values.