# Go - Error when using if statement around query

Tags: go

I am trying to run this - which would work fine in PHP but in Go I am getting an error:

```
if strings.EqualFold(update_status, "live") {
    stmt, err := dbmap.Prepare(
        "UPDATE Apps SET version=?,deploy_status=?,status=?,live_date=? WHERE id=?")
} else {
    stmt, err := dbmap.Prepare(
        "UPDATE Apps SET version=?,deploy_status=?,status=? WHERE id=?")
}
```

I get the error of `controllers/apps.go:1095: undefined: stmt in stmt.Exec`.

How can I change this so it will work?

Thanks

Comment: Issue is most likely you try to use `stmt` after the `if`, but they are scoped to the blocks they were created in. Declare `stmt` before the `if`, and just use assignment `=`.

Comment: Also related: [How do I create a variable in go only if a condition is true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533960/how-do-i-create-a-variable-in-go-only-if-a-condition-is-true)

Comment: @icza whats the correct way to define stmt?

Comment: See question marked as duplicate, also the related one, also the answer below.

Comment: @icza I can see the duplicate post, but it doesn't help me, I no how to cast an empty struct, but this isn't a struct?

Comment: Please read the answers to the linked questions, not just the questions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using [Short Variable Declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), so your `stmt` and `err` variables are scoped to the inner block of your conditions (both the `if` and the `else`.

This should do the trick:

```
var stmt *sql.Stmt
var err error
if strings.EqualFold(update_status, "live") {
    stmt, err = dbmap.Prepare(
        "UPDATE Apps SET version=?,deploy_status=?,status=?,live_date=? WHERE id=?")
} else {
    stmt, err = dbmap.Prepare(
        "UPDATE Apps SET version=?,deploy_status=?,status=? WHERE id=?")
}
//stmt is still defined here
```

Comment: This looks like what I was expecting - I just didnt no how, but I get the error of `undefined: sql in sql.Stmt` now.